# GLIB dependencies on RHEL5

Tags: rhel, glibc

I want to try to use the new Visual Studio Code on RHEL5. But when I run it, it says that I am missing some dependencies. How do I install them?

```
(15-08-07 19:21:25) <127> [~/VSCode]  
dev-dsk % ./Code 
./Code: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./Code)
./Code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./Code)
./Code: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /local/home/kasper/VSCode/libnode.so)
./Code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /local/home/kasper/VSCode/libnode.so)
./Code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /local/home/kasper/VSCode/libgcrypt.so.11)
./Code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /local/home/kasper/VSCode/libgcrypt.so.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but to get a new enough `glibc` for Visual Studio you'd need to upgrade to RHEL 7...

If you don't care for support you could try installing a newer RPM from somewhere but I'd recommend against it.

Comment: Sadly i am force to use RHEL5, so it will not be able to use it?

Comment: Realistically speaking you won't be able to use it, no.

Comment: Dam, thank for answering though.